# How to print a particular word from a sentence in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a 6 line output for a command that I run.
I need to select and print a particular word from that.
Can someone please help me.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of samples all over the web of how to use PoSH to extract text from files. As well as similar resources of how to print from PoSH.

Just do a search for 'PowerShell extract a word from a file' or 'print from powershell' using your search engine of choice, or use the same search on YouTube. You'll find a lot of data points on how to do this.

This kind of info exists in the PowerShell Help files as well.
See the help for these cmdlets.

```
(Get-Command -Name Get-Content).Parameters
Get-help -Name Get-Content -Full
Get-help -Name Get-Content -Examples

(Get-Command -Name Select-String).Parameters
Get-help -Name Select-String -Full
Get-help -Name Select-String -Examples

(Get-Command -Name Out-Printer).Parameters
Get-help -Name Out-Printer -Full
Get-help -Name Out-Printer -Examples
```